# Creating Graph with two or more values in second column

Tags: list-manipulation

For a social network analysis I have two columns. The second column has one, two or more values. Something like this:

```
data = {{A, {k, l, m}}, {B, {k, l, m, n, o}}, {C, {m, n, o}}}
```

I would like to make a relation between te value of the first column and for each value in the second column. So I would like to get:

```
data1 = {A -> k, A -> l, A -> m, B -> k,  B -> l, B -> m, B -> n, 
B -> o, C -> m, C -> n, C -> o}
```

Anyone a suggestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {{A, {k, l, m}}, {B, {k, l, m, n, o}}, {C, {m, n, o}}}

Flatten@(Thread[#[[1]] -> #[[2]]] & /@ data)

(* {A->k,A->l,A->m,B->k,B->l,B->m,B->n,B->o,C->m,C->n,C->o} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I will delete this answer later, but just for good fun (using `Riffle` and a funky feature of `Partition` :P)

```
Quiet[
 List @@
  Partition[
   Apply[Rule, Delete[Riffle[#[[2]], #[[1]], {1, -2, 2}], 0] & /@ data],
   2, 2, {1, -1}, {}]
 ]
```

Also quite silly

```
Delete[Thread@Rule@##, 0] & @@@ data
```

Answer (score 2):

Not so much different but without slots (`#`):

```
Rule @@@ Flatten[Thread /@ data, 1]
```